# Does suitecrm validate file upload like sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Ive tried uploading a simple php script that prints a message in the page in SUITECRM and surprisingly the file got uploaded without any validations.

here's my proof:

[image]

When i check the upload folder and found the file in .php format in this location http://localhost/upload/7ED577F6-C8F1-3C9E-E518-587D98FF8A7B_evil.php
Is this a bug or is this an issue that haven't been patch ? what i can do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no validation currently when a user uploads a file.

SuiteCRM simply checks for file permissions, maximum file size and not much more.

If you want to see for yourself [here is the code](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/blob/ef1b41965c056937894dd3018d3b149c9c25a9a9/include/SugarFields/Fields/Image/SugarFieldImage.php#L58)

Comment: is there any workarounds to restrict file uploads ?

Comment: It doesn't seem the answer, instead, it needs to be posted as a comment.